# Sqlite3 library giving thread error even though using -lpthread option

Tags: c++, sqlite, ide, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks IDE for my project.

So far, I downloaded the sqlite3 amalgation files, installed them using `make install` and linked the libsqlite3.a library to my project with 
**project**->**build options**->**linker settings** and added the libslite3.a file.

Now when I try to build my project, I get some errors like `undefined reference to pthread_mutex_trylock` or `undefined reference to pthread_create`.

I have included `pthread`, `thread`, `mutex` headers in my main, I added the option `-lpthread` and `pthread` alternatively in the **project**->**build options**->**other copiler options** and still I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l<library>` is linker option, not a compiler option, so in Code::Blocks
it goes in the **Other linker options**

Removing `-lpthread` from the compiler options and adding it to the linker
options will probably be sufficient.

However the correct, portable, way to enable `pthreads` multithreading in GCC is
to add the option `-pthread` (not `-lpthread`) to *both* the compiler options:-

**Project**->**Build options**->**Compiler settings** -> **Other compiler options**

and the linker options:

**Project**->**Build options**->**Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**

This option tells both the compiler to do the right things to
generate `pthreads` compliant code and tells the linker to do the right things to
link it with the POSIX threads library of the host platform.

To use `pthreads` in your program, `#include <pthreads.h>`

Comment: The project builds if I link the sqlite3.so file instead of the .a file. Is it sufficient? Your solution works, but now I have a undefined ref to dlerror, which I can not fix if I also link -dl as an option in linker options

Comment: `libsqite3.so` is fine. Just use `-lsqlite3` in **Other linker options** and the linker will pick the `.so` for preference. You will need to provide its path in **Search Directories** -> **Linker** if your `libsqlite3.so` is not in one of the default lib dirs `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`